# Move commit to different branch

Tags: git

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to move commit from branch A to branch B.

I was working on "develop" branch, then created a new one, let's say "featureA"
to start developing new feature. I made 2 commits, but first one should have gone to "develop" instead of "featureA" because it was just a small fix, but I forgot to change branch, so can I simply move commit 1 to branch "develop" and remove it from "featureA"?

Changes are still not pushed, just local.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case it is easy.  To see why, draw (part of) the commit graph.

You started with something like this:

```
...--o--*   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

You then created a new branch name, `feature`, pointing to the same tip-of-`develop` commit `*`.  You attached your `HEAD` to the new branch, giving:

```
...--o--*   <-- develop, feature (HEAD), origin/develop
```

Now you made two new commits.  Let's call them `A` and `B` rather than using their real hash IDs, which are big and ugly and forgettable.  Commit `A` has, as its parent, commit `*`, and commit `B` has commit `A` as its parent, and the name `feature` now points to commit `*`:

```
...--o--*   <-- develop, origin/develop
         \
          A--B   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Leaving `feature` alone, let's tell Git to move the name `develop` to point to commit `A`, the minor fix you want to have on your `develop`:

```
...--o--*   <-- origin/develop
         \
          A   <-- develop
           \
            B   <-- feature
```

I've removed the attached `HEAD` temporarily since there are several ways to adjust `develop` like this and `HEAD` may re-attach as we do them.  This is the final picture you want: no commits have changed at all, but your local name `develop` now points to the first commit, while `feature` points to the second one.

So: how shall we do it?

One quite-safe method (can't lose any work) is to `git checkout develop` first, then use `git merge --ff-only` to fast-forward `develop` to the correct commit.  That's commit `A`, which is one step back from `feature`, so we can do this:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --ff-only feature~1
```

This will leave you with `develop` pointing to commit `A` (and your `HEAD` attached to `develop`, so you have to `git checkout feature` to keep going).

Another way is to check out `develop` and use `git reset --hard` to move the label `develop` to any arbitrary commit (while also updating your index / staging-area and your work-tree).  This is essentially the same as above, but it lets you move the name anywhere, even if that's not a sensible move, so the above is probably preferable.

Yet another way is to use `git branch -f` to force move the name to the location you want:

```
git branch -f develop feature~1
```

This leaves your `HEAD` attached to `feature`, so that you don't have to `git checkout feature` to keep working.  However, like the `git reset` method, it's not very safe as it lets you move the name to *any* commit, even if that makes no sense.

Finally, there's a very sneaky way to update `develop` in a fast-forward fashion (a la `git merge --ff-only`) without checking out `develop`—in fact you *need* to stay on some other branch to do it:

```
git push . feature~1:develop
```

This has your Git call up your own Git, and propose to itself that it should move the name `develop` to point to the commit whose hash ID was obtained by parsing `feature~1`.  Your Git will obey your Git if and only if this is a fast-forward, since there is no force flag here.

Use whichever of these you like; they all achieve the same result in the end, except for where your `HEAD` is attached.

Comment: Everything works as you wrote, thank you very much, but I'm a little bit confused
about git merge --ff-only feature~1 command, can you elaborate more on this, or send some useful sources to learn more?

Comment: @pablocity: `git merge` is a tricky little command because—like too many other Git commands, in my opinion—it can do one of several different things. One of these is a true merge, in which Git creates a new commit that has two (or more but let's not go there) parents. The other is what Git calls, variously, a *fast-forward* or, especially when done via `git merge`, a *fast-forward merge* (kind of a misnomer as there is no actual merging occurring!). Fast-forward is actually a property of label movement. Note that when we use `git branch -f` or `git reset`, we move some branch name ... 1/

Comment: ... from wherever it pointed before, to any commit we choose. The motion of that label (in this case, a branch name) can be a *fast-forward* or a *non-fast-forward*, and what distinguishes these is whether the new commit has the original commit as an ancestor, i.e., whether, by starting at the new commit and working back through the commit graph, we can reach the previous commit. If we *can* reach the previous commit, this change was a fast-forward. 2/

Comment: Both `git push` and `git fetch` favor fast-forward operations: they will happily adjust branch names, and for fetch, remote-tracking names, that result in fast-forwards. They object to non-fast-forward updates, requiring `--force` or equivalent. This guarantees that the change, whatever it is, preserves all the *existing* commits and merely adds some more (or in the degenerate case, changes nothing at all—the label already points to the new commit). Anyway, that's great for fetch and push, but what about merge? 3/

Comment: When you do *any* `git merge <commit-hash-or-name>` operation, the merge code inspects the current commit (using `HEAD` to find its hash ID) and the target commit (whatever you named on the command line), and does one of these ancestor tests. If the current commit is an ancestor of the target commit, the merge operation is deemed unnecessary: a fast-forward will do. This is where `--ff-only` and `--no-ff` enter the picture: the former *requires* it and the latter *forbids* it, forcing Git to make a merge commit instead. 4/

Comment: If a fast-forward is possible and allowed (or even required), Git will move the current branch name forward to the target commit. Because it's the currently-checked-out commit, though, this also requires updating the index and work-tree, as if via `git reset --hard`. So Git does that, too. (Note that `git merge` makes sure, very early on, that the index and work-tree are clean, so that the hard reset does not lose work.) So that's what a fast-forward "merge" really is: a controlled `git reset --hard`. 5/5

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git cherry-pick <commit>` from the target branch to copy the commit there (`<commit>` can be the branch name if it's the last commit).

You can use `git reset --hard HEAD^` to erase the last commit from the original branch.

Comment: Building on this, if the commits _were_ already pushed to remote, `git revert <commit>` would be better in place of `git reset --hard HEAD^` to "erase" the commit.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, but one thing, if commit which I wnat to remove isn't last one, can I use git reset --hard commitName to remove specific one?

Comment: Question asked to *move* the commit; this will copy it.  That can be corrected (either with more cherry-picking or a rebase), but it turns out to be overly complicated, considering that in this case the only thing "wrong" is the location of the branch refs, and the existing commits can be used as-is.  See torek's answer.  (And `revert` is nothing but cost in this case, since nothing has been pushed.)

Comment: @pablocity: No; that will reset to that commit, deleting everything after it.  Use `git rebase -i` and delete the commit you want.

Comment: This is all correct as well: if you *do* need to copy a commit (to change the graph's structure, instead of / in addition to changing which commit each name points-to), `git cherry-pick` will do it. Git books teach this stuff in what is in my opinion the wrong order: cherry-pick should come first, then rebase, because rebase is an automated series of cherry-picks. (And in all cases, the key to understanding any of it starts with the *graph* and how snapshots become change-sets.)