# How to move the last commit of a branch to the first commit of its featured branch and change the base of the featured branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, rebase, git-rebase

here's my problem:
I have this development branch which I am supposed to get my new branches from it.
I took this branch named `descendingOrder` and committed and pushed everything I wanted to do.
Then I had a totally different and new task. so when I was in `descendingOrder` I used the command `git checkout -b featureTest` and made a new branch. but I had two mistakes here:

1- My last commit on  `descendingOrder` was supposed to be on the new branch `feature test`. but I mistakenly committed it on `descendingOrder`.

2- The `feature test` branch was supposed to be taken from the `development` branch. but I mistakenly took it from `descendingOrder`.

Now I want to move back the `feature test` to `development` and also add the last local commit of `descendingOrder`  at the first of the new featured branch.

I also saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089630/move-commit-to-different-branch) but it didn't help much.

Comment: If you could describe with some ASCII the current branches graph (or add a screenshot if there is no confidential information) and also the expected one, it will be easier to understand and to answer to your question...

Comment: Ensure you are on the `feature test` branch then rebase it onto `development`, removing the commits you don't want during the rebase. You can then hard reset the `descendingOrder` branch back one commit to remove the unwanted commit.

Comment: Why didn't the linked question help? It looks very similar to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options which will all give you the same history eventually (with different commit hashes of course):

1. There was only a single commit on `descendingOrder`. Nothing to do with `feature test`, it already contains the commit as first commit. You can delete or move back `descendingOrder` by one commit: `git branch -f descendingOrder descendingOrder^`
2. There are already multiple commits on `descendingOrder` and `feature test` currently contains all of them. Rebase can help:

   ```
   git rebase --onto development 'feature test^' 'feature test'
   git branch -f descendingOrder descendingOrder^
   ```

   This will take the last commit of `feature test` copies it on top of `development`. Your `feature test` branch will then only contain this single commit (not in development). Afterwards, `descendingOrder` needs to be moved back one commit.

   If there are multiple commits on `feature test` that need to be rebased/moved, replace `'feature test^'` with `'feature test~N'` with `N` being the number of commits you want to copy.

   This option will work too if there was only a single commit on `feature test`, but it's more complicated than option 1.
3. Use cherry-pick:

   ```
   git checkout -B 'feature test' development
   git cherry-pick descendingOrder
   git branch -f descendingOrder descendingOrder^
   ```

   This first destroys and recreates your branch at the last commit of `development`, then copies the last commit of `descendingOrder`. Again, `descendingOrder` needs to be moved back.
4. Use an interactive rebase:

   ```
   git rebase -i development 'feature test'
   git branch -f descendingOrder descendingOrder^
   ```

   In the todo-list in the editor, remove all but the last commit (or the last N commits, if you want to keep multiple commits in the branch). After the rebase has complete, move back the `descendingOrder` branch.